# How to create node.js html server with css

Tags: html, css, node.js, http, server

Im trying to create simple node.js server for html using http and express

It's working, but css don't showing

Here is code of my server

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static("css"));

var router = express.Router()

app.use('/',router)

router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.htm")
})

app.listen(8080)
```

And code of my server, what created using http

```
const http = require("http")
const port = 8080
const fs = require('fs')

const server = http.createServer(function(req,res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', (error, data) => {
        if(error) {
            res.writeHead("404")
              res.write("Error. File not found.")
        } else {
            res.use
            res.write(data)
        }
        res.end();
    })

})

server.listen(port, function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error)
    } else {
        console.log("server is listening on port " + port)
    }
})
```

all my html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Domodinak</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

also css

```
body {
    background-color: deeppink;
}
```

if you know how to help me, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you're addressing `css` folder correctly. It depends on your project folder structure. It is suggested to save your static files in a folder called `public` and then save your files in separated folder like `js` and `css`. For example, i assume that you have a `src` folder which is your directory for express server file, another folder alongside the `src` folder, you have a `public` folder with `css` subfolder.
Put your stylesheet file in `css` subfolder, and html file in just `public` folder and then change your code to this:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));

// var router = express.Router()

// app.use('/',router)

// router.get("/", (req, res) => {
//  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.htm")
// })

app.listen(8080)
```

Your project structure should looks like this:

```
|-public -| css -| style.css
          index.html
|-src -| app.js
```

Run the server file then check your browser with just `localhost:8080`. It serves `index.html` from static directory which you passed to express earlier.